# Turtle Graphics Color Error Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to run this turtle function:

```
from turtle import *

def main():


    color('red', 'yellow')
    begin_fill()
    while True:
        forward(200)
        left(170)
        if abs(pos()) < 1:
            break
    end_fill()
    done()

main()
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\eardery\Desktop\Final Exam Practice\turtlepolygon.py", line 1, in <module>
 from turtle import *
File "C:\Users\eardery\Desktop\Final Exam Practice\turtle.py", line 234
raise Error, "no color arguments"
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have no idea what this means.

Answer (score 1):

you have a file named `turtle.py` in the same folder ... you should not name files the same as libraries ... you are importing from your local turtle.py file

rename `turtle.py` (in this same folder) to `myturtle.py` and it should be fine

Comment: Thank you it works now! I thought it had to be named turtle.py in order for Python to know which file I'm asking for. So is turtle just automatically assumed by Python in the same way as math when you import it?

Comment: @GooseLaMoose `turtle.py` is a file that exists in your python library.  When you do `import turtle`, Python looks for a file called `turtle.py` in your local directory first, then in the python library.  Because you had one named `turtle.py` in your local directory, it loaded that first.  Renaming it to `myturtle.py` solves this be not "shadowing" the `turtle.py` in the library.